# Add photos using bazaarvoice sdk

Tags: android, review

I have to submit multiple photos using bazaarvoice sdk, not getting how to do that, I found something like

```
ReviewSubmissionRequest submission = new ReviewSubmissionRequest.Builder(submitAction, productId)  
        .userNickname("xxxx")
        .title("Review title")
        .reviewText("This is the review text the user adds about how great the product is!")
        .addPhoto(localImageFile, "caption")
        .build();
```

but, still not clear

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add many photos by calling addPhoto multiple times.

```
final ReviewSubmissionRequest submission = new ReviewSubmissionRequest.Builder(submitAction, productId)  
  .userNickname("xxxx")
  .title("Review title")
  .reviewText("This is the review text the user adds about how great the product is!")
  .addPhoto(localImageFile1, "caption 1")
  .addPhoto(localImageFile2, "caption 2")
  .addPhoto(localImageFile3, "caption 3")
  .build();
```